# How to maintain Bash output formatting in python REPL

Tags: python, bash, shell, ipython

I have a python script that creates a thin wrapper around the bash shell. It wraps bash calls via the subprocess module, takes the output, and does some work on it.

My output contains newlines "\n" but no additional color or space formatting (i.e. tabs).

Within Ipython, you can execute shell builtins, such as "ls", directly.  The output is formatted (with coloring and spacing) almost identically to the output of executing the "ls" command directly from the bash shell.

Any idea how Ipython mimics shell output formatting? Are they special casing different commands?

If you are not familiar with Ipython, any thoughts on how I could recreate the bash formatting in my python script's REPL without having to create an explicit mapping and logic for different commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong here, but I don't think ipython does *anything* here.

When you type `!ls`, this just shells out to `ls`. On my system, I just see a plain black-on-white one-file-per-line listing, exactly the same as if I'd redirected `ls` to a file and then done a `cat` on that file. Even if `ls` is aliased to `ls -FG` in my bash shell, `!ls` ignores that.

So, if you're getting any fancy formatting, it's because you've configured `ls` (e.g., via env variables) to do something fancy.

However, there is one thing that may be different between ipython and your code: I believe ipython is just letting the subprocess print to its stdout. But you're capturing that stdout and manually routing it to your own output. This means that bash, and all of its child processes, will be able to tell that their stdout is not a TTY, and may change their output accordingly.

So, you can't just redirect bash's stdout to a pipe, you have to redirect it to a [pty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal), or to something else that will act like a TTY.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right.  I just tried it with subprocess.call and it was properly formatted.  Silly on my part. Thanks!